Rstatix sign_test problems
I just cannot get anything in this package to work, and I'm completely confused about why. As an example, I was trying to figure out how to use the sign_test part of the package. Nothing would work (it just always errored out), and when I finally used an example online.
https://www.datanovia.com/en/lessons/sign-test-in-r/
Naturally this errors out as well, despite me using it very precisely as intended:
Error in UseMethod("sign_test") :
no applicable method for 'sign_test' applied to an object of class "data.frame"
I've used R a long time, and have never struggled with getting a package to run (at all) like I have with rstatix. Does this package actually work?
